# Java check if first digit of int is 0

Tags: java, if-statement, integer

So the question is very simple.
How to check in java if first digit of an `int` is `0`;

Say I have:

```
int y = 0123;
int n = 123;
```

Now I need an if statement that would return true for `y` and false for `n`.

Comment: That's not possible. The 0 is removed at compile time. During runtime, the values are the exact same, making your check impossible. If you were using ``String``s to store these values, it would be possible.

Comment: Maybe you could also tell us why you think a leading non significant zero matters to you.  Mathematically speaking, it should not matter.

Comment: @f1sh Actually, prefixing an int with a "0" in this case turns it into an octal value, so they're not the same in all cases (including this one, the one you prefixed with a 0 would have a decimal value of 83, so you *could* tell to a certain degree.) But I'm not sure that's what you're after, and other than that, it's not possible to detect this at runtime.

Comment: The reason I need this is because I'm working with self made dates. And in case I have a date '03.04.2018' I want to print it as 3. 4. 2018, without the 0s in the beginning.

Comment: But how are you storing your date ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is pretty strange for one reason: **An int value cannot start by 0**. But if you store your value in a String, you could check it easily like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String y = "0123";
    String n = "123";

    System.out.println(startByZero(y));
    System.out.println(startByZero(n));
}

public static boolean startByZero(String value) {
    return value.startsWith("0");
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

**EDIT:**
Like Oleksandr suggest, you can use also:

```
public static boolean startByZero(String value) {
    return value.charAt(0) == '0';
}
```

This solution is more efficient than the first. (but at my own opinion it's also less readable)

Comment: What about the int `0` ? Does it need to return true or false ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your

```
y = 0123
```

will be considered as **octal base** but

```
 n = 123
```

is an **decimal base**.

Now when you do

`if (y == n )`

the numbers will be compared based on decimal base always.

You'll have to do conversions from octal to decimal or vice-versa based on your requirements.

You could also use `Strings` as @Valentin recommeneded.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seems on topic but based on OP's comment :

> The reason I need this is because I'm working with self made dates. And in case I have a date '03.04.2018' I want to print it as 3. 4. 2018, without the 0s in the beginning.
>   Lommmp

---

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, you should use java time API to parse and format your dates :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("03.04.2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.yyyy"));
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M.d.yyyy")));
```

> 3.4.2018

Answer (score -1):

String.format("%01d",number);
for Zero padding with length 1.
like 0123
Read from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-examples/